# What is the meaning of log moment

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In the basic probability and statistics, we are familiar with the meanings of the first moment and the second moment:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]\mathrm{: the~average~of~}X$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2\mathrm{: the~variance~of~}X$$

However, for the log moment,

$$\mathbb{E}[\log X]$$

it is somehow esoteric to figure out its meaning.

Actually, I come up with this question because I learned that the maximum entropy distribution subject to the following constraints is the gamma distribution.

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=g_1$$
$$\mathbb{E}[\log X]=g_2$$

where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are some constant.

Maybe some realization of the random variable $X$ has specific meanings in both of its first moment and log moment so that the gamma distribution can be its maximum entropy distribution.

For more information about the maximum entropy distribution, please refers to
[http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~taneja/book/node14.html](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/%7Etaneja/book/node14.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One intuition that might be applicable is that $\log(X)$ in some sense measures magnitude. So if it's base 10, for instance (it's usually the natural log, but the same intuition applies), $\log(X)$ says something about whether $X$ is in the order of 10's, 100's, 1000's or more. So the sufficient statistics of the gamma let you control the average value, but also the average scale (incidentally, and likely not coincidentally, often the name of said parameter).